# Should you use a reference for an std::unordered_map iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, reference

I'm currently debugging a crash in an open source game, and the offending line seems to be this:

```
for( auto &special: special_attacks ) {
```

Where `special_attacks` is defined as follows:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, mon_special_attack> special_attacks;
```

I suspect that the issue here is that since `special` is an iterator rather than a value, this code might actually be creating a reference to the return value of the internal `special_attacks.begin()` call. This suspicion is backed up by the fact that leaving out the `&` leads to functional code (modifying `special.second` will also modify the copy in the `unordered_map`).

So when iterating over `std::unordered_map`, should we just always use a value for the iterator rather than a reference?

Comment: re "special is an iterator", no, it's not.

Comment: See e.g. [this range-for reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) it shows an example implementation which will show you that `special` (in your case) isn't an iterator.

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's just a pair.. Geez, auto makes me dumb sometimes. Now it's especially weird that not using a reference still allows me to modify the values in the container.

Comment: Ah.. nevermind, I was reading my debug output wrong.. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...since special is an iterator rather than a value...

No, it's not. The value type of `special_attacks` will be `std::pair<const std::string, mon_special_attack>`, so `auto& special` will have type `std::pair<const std::string, mon_special_attack>&` (possibly reference to const). That is not an iterator - your bug is somewhere else.

I suspect based on your description that `special_attacks` is actually `const`, so your attempts to modify the values through a const reference is failing to compile.

Comment: Yep, my bad. Don't think there's anything else to add to this..?

Comment: re your edit: No, it compiles fine, it just crashes.. there seems to be something modifying the container during the iteration, which is weird because the keys are always extracted as const. But thank you.